# How to achieve breakpoint upload in android-async-http?

Tags: android, http, android-async-http

My server support breakpoint upload. How to achieve breakpoint upload in android-async-http?

breakpoint upload mean "breakpoint resume" upload

Comment: what is break point upload?

Comment: guess you meant "breakpoint resume" upload?

Comment: breakpoint upload mean "breakpoint resume" upload

Comment: As I responded you on https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/901 this is not currently possible with library, and will require you to implement custom pause/resume logic on both sides (client and server)